# MySQL Query - listing data from 2 tables where NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate point usage by customers of an online store. Over time, customers acquire points. As points are redeemed, the value of the *customer.points* is modified to reflect points remaining to redeem. Any additional points acquired are also added to *customer.points*. Because of this, the only true mechanism for determining the number of points a customer has had over the lifetime of an account is to SUM total usage with remaining points (*`order`.total* + *customer.points*).

The query below returns the desired results, BUT ONLY FOR THOSE CUSTOMERS WHO HAVE REDEEMED POINTS. What I would like, since ALL customers have points, is to also be able to return the points balance for those WHO HAVE NOT REDEEMED points.

```
SELECT customer.store_id, customer.customer_id, `order`.total + customer.points 
    AS allpoints, customer.firstname, customer.lastname 
    FROM `order`
    INNER JOIN customer ON `order`.customer_id = customer.customer_id
    WHERE (customer.store_id =3)
    GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use an `left outer join`, which will return all rows for the table on the left side of the join, and only return rows for the table on the right side if records exist.  This does mean that you'll need to handle `null` values for the `order` table when a record doesn't exist.

```
SELECT
  customer.store_id,
  customer.customer_id,
  isnull(order.total, 0) + customer.points AS allpoints,
  customer.firstname,
  customer.lastname
FROM customer
  LEFT OUTER JOIN order ON order.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE (customer.store_id =3)
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```